# Trying to parse form data

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

```html
<form action="/recommend" method="POST">
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="name">Restaurant name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name1" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="cuisine">Type of cuisine</label>
    <input
        type="text"
        id="cuisine"
        name="cuisine"
        placeholder="e.g. Indian"
        required
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="website">Restaurant website</label>
    <input
        type="url"
        id="website"
        name="website"
        placeholder="abcd@gmail.com"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="description">Why do you recommend it?</label>
    <textarea
        name="description"
        id="description"
        rows="5"
        required
    ></textarea>
  </div>
  <button>Share Restaurant</button>
</form>
```

**NODEJS CODE**

```js
app.post("/recommend", (req, res) => {
  const restaurant    = req.body;   // const restaurant = req.body.name1;
  console.log(restaurant);          // I am not getting any output in console 
  const filePath          = path.join(__dirname, "data", "restaurants.json");
  const fileData          = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const storedrestaurants = JSON.parse(fileData);

  storedrestaurants.push(restaurant);
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(storedrestaurants));
  res.redirect("/confirm");
});
```

**output in JSON FILE INSTEAD OF ADDING FORM DATA ITS ADDING NULL **

```
[null,null,null]
```

**ERROR**

Instead of saving form data in JSON file It is saving null. HELP me to solve this error.
If I am consoling the restaurant then in console there is no output if I will add name attribute after body in
`const restaurant = req.body.name1`
then it is giving `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined  (reading 'name1')` this error.

Comment: where is your [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) ?

Comment: Log req.body directly to see what its structure

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is a problem with the way your Node.js code accesses the form data.

Then, check to see that your Node.js application has the body-parser middleware present in order to parse the form input. Add the following code to your Node.js file to accomplish this:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

The name attribute of each input element in the HTML form must then be specified in order to access the form data. Since each input element in your scenario has a name property supplied, you may retrieve the form data by using the name attribute as shown below:

```
app.post('/recommend', (req, res) => {
  const restaurant = req.body; // get the entire form data as an object
  console.log(restaurant); // log the form data to the console
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'data', 'restaurants.json');
  const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const storedrestaurants = JSON.parse(fileData);

  storedrestaurants.push(restaurant);
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(storedrestaurants));
  res.redirect('/confirm');
});
```

Note that req.body will have an object with keys as the 'name' attribute values of the form inputs and values as the input values. For instance, 'req.body' would be the following if the user typed "John" in the name input box and "123 Main St" in the address input field:

```
{
  name1: 'John',
  address: '123 Main St',
  cuisine: 'Indian',
  website: 'abcd@gmail.com',
  description: 'This restaurant has great food!'
}
```

Therefore, to access the name1 field, you can use req.body.name1.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<body>
  <form id="formEle">
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="name">Restaurant name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name1" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="address">Address</label>
      <input type="text" id="address" name="address" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="cuisine">Type of cuisine</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="cuisine"
        name="cuisine"
        placeholder="e.g. Indian"
        required
        />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="website">Restaurant website</label>
      <input
        type="url"
        id="website"
        name="website"
        placeholder="abcd@gmail.com"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="description">Why do you recommend it?</label>
      <textarea
        name="description"
        id="description"
        rows="5"
        required
        ></textarea>
    </div>
    <button>Share Restaurant</button>
  </form>
  <script>
    let form = document.getElementById("formEle")
    form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const response = await fetch('/recommend', {
        method: 'post',
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name1: document.getElementById("name"),
          // Address
          // Type of cuisine
          // Restaurant website
        })
      })
      const data = await response.json()
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

In NodeJS:

```js
app.post("/recommend", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
})
```

Make sure your route names are same and just see how fetch fetch method work!

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.